# What is the key to making beef soft?

Tags: beef

I bought chuck roast beef from the store but when I cooked it for my beef noodle soup, it was a little hard.

My mom told me sometimes adding salt will suck out the water amd make it hard. I'm not sure if this was the reason why though.

Are there any key things to keep in mind when cooking beef to keep it soft?

Comment: While the phrasing of the question was somewhat different, please see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/what-makes-a-moist-steak which discusses keeping steak moist (which is usually another way of perceiving soft in foods); the answer is general to meat and not just steak.  Chuck is a low and slow cut that responds well to techniques like braising and barbecue.   However, there is no single answer for all beef.

Comment: Related and basically duplicates: [How do I make the beef in my beef stroganoff more tender?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22447), [How do you cook grass-fed beef so it is not tough?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5297), [Tough roast.. what's going wrong?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20920), [Cooking beef: how to make it tender?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13352), [Cooking Cheap Cuts of Beef](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20775)...

Comment: ...and [Tough roast.. what's going wrong?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20920) and probably a few more. Basically the answer is always the same, get good meat and don't overcook it.

Comment: thanks for the redirect! sorry I couldn't find that question